# La consola no interpreta el salto de linea "\n"

Tags: python

```py
def estado(self):
    print("Marca: ", self.marca, "\nModelo: ", self.modelo, "\nEn marcha: ", 
        self.enmarcha, "\nAcelerando: ", self.acelera, "\nFrenando: ", self.frena)
```

---

En la consola se muestra así:

```
('Marca: ', 'Honda', '\nModelo: ', 'CBR', '\nEn Marcha: ', False, '\nAcelerando: ', False, '\nFrenando: ', False)

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: seguro que no has puesto unos paréntesis de más? parece que lo que imprime es una tupla

Comment: Estás usando Python 2.7? En esa versión de Python `print` no era una función y no llevaba por tanto paréntesis alrededor de sus parámetros y al ponerlos lo que estarías imprimiendo sería una tupla, lo que encaja con lo que se ve. Pero Python 2.7 está marcado como obsoleto desde hace ya varios años. Te recomiendo que te pases a Python 3.x (van ya por la 3.10)

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sí, estoy usando Phyton 2.7, he intentado instalar Phyton 3.10, pero sale un error indicando que no se puede instalar en Windows 7.

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo a programar en este lenguaje, tengo varias dudas. Es necesario utilizar una versión de Windows mas actualizada o Python 3.10 se puede instalar en Windows 7?

Comment: La version 3.10 requiere un windows más moderno. En windows 7 puedes instalar la 3.8 (descarga aqui --> https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya instale Python 3.8 y la consola interpretó correctamente el salto de página.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque el problema ya ha sido resuelto actualizando a Python3, querría explicar un poco mejor lo que estaba ocurriendo, ya que no se trata de que "la consola no interpete el salto de línea". De hecho el problema no tenía nada qué ver con la consola ni con saltos de línea.

Ocurre que en Python2.7 `print` no era una función, sino una palabra especial del lenguaje (como `while` o `if`) y como tal no usaba paréntesis para delimitar los parámetros. Es decir, tendrías que haberla usado así por ejemplo

```py
marca = "Honda"
modelo = "CBR"
print "Marca", marca, "\nModelo", modelo
```

Esto funcionará correctamente en python2 y mostrará:

```
Marca Honda
Modelo CBR
```

Observa cómo `print` no usa paréntesis. Al ponerlos estarías agrupando "en un sólo parámetro" de tipo tupla las cuatro cadenas:

```
print("Marca", marca, "\nModelo", modelo)
```

En esta ocasión `print` está recibiendo un sólo "valor" para mostrar, y ese valor es una tupla compuesta de cuatro cadenas. Python elige mostrar las tuplas en la misma forma en la que las introduces en el código fuente, es decir, entre paréntesis, separadas por comas y con cada cadena entre comillas y sin interpretar los caracteres especiales como \n. Es decir, muestra esto:

```
('Marca', 'Honda', '\nModelo', 'CBR')
```

En Python3 en cambio `print()` se ha convertido en una función, por lo que ahora requiere los paréntesis alrededor de sus parámetros. El primer ejemplo que puse que funcionaba correctamente en python2, dará ahora un error de sintaxis en Python3, por no tener los paréntesis necesarios.

El segundo ejemplo con paréntesis funcionará correctamente, y no sera interpretado como una tupla, porque los paréntesis se interpretan como parte de la sintaxis necesaria para invocar una función.

Si quisiéramos en Python3 pasarle una tupla a `print()` habría que usar paréntesis de nuevo dentro de los paréntesis. Así:

```
print(("Marca", marca, "\nModelo", modelo))
```

Y en este caso volcará por pantalla la tupla en el formato que hemos visto antes. Como ves no se trataba de un problema de que la consola no intepretara el salto de línea, sino del tipo de datos que le estabas pasando a print.

Comment: Ok, Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona:

```
def estado(self):
    marca="Hyundai"
    modelo="i10"
    enmarcha=True
    acelera=False
    frena=True

    print("Marca: ", marca, "\nModelo: ", modelo, "\nEn Marcha: ",
          enmarcha, "\nAcelerando: ", acelera, "\nFrenando: ", frena)


estado("a")
```

produce:

```
Marca:  Hyundai 
Modelo:  i10 
En Marcha:  True 
Acelerando:  False 
Frenando:  True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Probablemente estás mostrando el resultado de alguna otra cosa, distinta a la llamada a función.